# PhP and Js writing problems in html file

Tags: javascript, php, html

so here is my problem :

There is my index.html and I want to write on it with php and javascript in order to check that the text is correct. When I start the index.html from one of my computer the javascript text displays correctly but not the php.

So I create a .htaccess and launch the index.html again using mylocal server then the php text display correctly but the javascript isn't anymore (using write or alert)

So what do I have to do in order to be able to use both ?

here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>

    <?php include 'parsing.php';?>

    <script>

    write("write");
    alert("alert");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the page should be server by a webserver with a php plugin. how do you test your page?

Comment: Javascript is run in the *browser*. It will always work (unless you have it disabled). PHP is run on the *server*. You do have a server, right?

Comment: What does the `parsing.php` have in it? Maybe you have `die` or `exit` in there?

Answer (score 0):

the parsing.php is as simple as that :
    
yes, I have a webserver with the php plugin that's why it works in the second case only.
I am testing the page with this page : http://localhost/index.html

Thanks for your answers I think it was caused by my company proxy or something like that (their computer are full of problems anyway...)
I retried afterwards without changing anything and now it works.

Thanks for your time.